# Increase an Image's clickable area

Tags: libgdx

Edit: I am using LibGDX framework.

There is an `Image` Actor, which is:

- Attached to a `Stage`.
- Has an `OnClickListener`, e.g.:`image.addListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });`

This Image's touchable area is fixed on the image's width and height.
I want to increase the touchable area by *N* pixels.
How can I achieve this?

Here's an illustration:
(red rectangle = touchable/clickable area)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` already supports this out of the box. The actor can be bigger than the drawn image itself. You can supply a `Scaling` strategy for the drawn picture and in case you use `Scaling.none`, the drawn picture will be independent of the actor's size.

```
image.setScaling(Scaling.none)
int N = 30;
image.setSize(image.getImageWidth() + N, image.getImageHeight() + N);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach it, is to have a custom image view, with the actual Image View inside a RelativeLayout. The relative layout has padding and/or margin set, so that it is bigger than the imageView. then, when you set the onClicklistener, set it on the relative layout as well as the image layout (in your custom class)

Comment: It's [libgdx] tagged, android stuff is not relevant here.